# Filter using keyword Pandas Dataframe Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filtering

I have data stored in the data frame. Now I want to filter out the data within specific columns using Keywords.
For Example:
let my dataframe be:

```
    customer    product         state
0   shyam       pen drive       delhi
1   suresh      hard disk       punjab
2   shanu       USB pen drive   haryana
3   rohan       pen drive 16gb  uttarpradesh
```

Now I want to filter this dataframe in column 'product' with values containing 'pen' only.
so the result should look like:

```
    customer    product         state
0   shyam       pen drive       delhi
2   shanu       USB pen drive   haryana
3   rohan       pen drive 16gb  uttarpradesh
```

Every suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
df[df['product'].str.contains('pen')]
```

Output:

```
  customer         product         state
0    shyam       pen drive         delhi
2    shanu   USB pen drive       haryana
3    rohan  pen drive 16gb  uttarpradesh
```

`.str`, string accessor, can be slow, use list comprehension for better performance:

```
df[['pen' in i for i in df['product']]]
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Also is there any way to find using multiple keywords, like: `df[df['product'].str.contains('pen','hard','something_else')]`

Comment: Yes. use regex `.str.contains('pen|hard|something_else')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = df.loc[df.product.str.contains('pen')]
```